# can't resolve symbol scala play2 with mysql result

Tags: mysql, scala, play2-mini

Guys I am trying to get some results from mysql database and I am having error with fetching it onto scala.html file. Here are my codes:

```
/*Customers.scala. Its controller*/
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models.Customers

object Customers extends Controller{

    def customer = Action{

        val nb_customers = Customers.allCustomers

        Ok(views.html.customer(nb_customers)) //I am having error here.

    }
    // End of customer Action.

}
// End of Customer controller.



/*Now Customers.scala model*/

package models
import anorm._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

case class Customers(CustomersID: Int, Name: String)

object Customers {

    def allCustomers = {

        DB.withConnection {implicit connection =>

            SQL("Select * from Customers")().map{row =>

                Customers(

                    CustomersID = row[Int]("CustomersID"),
                    Name = row[String]("Name")

                )
                // End of Customers object.
            }.toList
            // SQL ends.

        }
        // With connection.

    }
    // End of allCustomers.

}
// End of of Customers.
```

Please note, I am using JDBC driver for mysql connection in conf/application.conf file

Please help me out here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post the error and at least the header of the view that you're trying to render.

Comment: Thanks mate, the error i got, saysing -value allCustomers is not a member of object controllers.Customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a namespace conflict between your `Customers` controller and model, as both are in the scope. There are two things you can do to fix this.

1. Rename your model to something different, like `Customer`.
2. Change `Customers.allCustomers` to `models.Customers.allCustomers` to differentiate from `controllers.Customers`.